# K-means clustering using Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, k-means

I found the following code on the Internet.  I think there is a problem in type conversion.
I tried to solving some of it but still there are few that elude me.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

 public class Cluster {

    public List points;
    public Point centroid;
    public int id;

    //Creates a new Cluster
    public Cluster(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.points = new ArrayList();
        this.centroid = null;
    }

    public List getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void addPoint(Point point) {
        points.add(point);
    }

    public void setPoints(List points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public Point getCentroid() {
        return centroid;
    }

    public void setCentroid(Point centroid) {
        this.centroid = centroid;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void clear() {
        points.clear();
    }

    public void plotCluster() {
        System.out.println("[Cluster: " + id+"]");
        System.out.println("[Centroid: " + centroid + "]");
        System.out.println("[Points: \n");
        for(Point p : points) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }

}

public class Point {

    private double x = 0;
    private double y = 0;
    private int cluster_number = 0;

    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        this.setX(x);
        this.setY(y);
    }

    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double getX()  {
        return this.x;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return this.y;
    }

    public void setCluster(int n) {
        this.cluster_number = n;
    }

    public int getCluster() {
        return this.cluster_number;
    }

    //Calculates the distance between two points.
    protected static double distance(Point p, Point centroid) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((centroid.getY() - p.getY()), 2) + Math.pow((centroid.getX() - p.getX()), 2));
    }

    //Creates random point
    protected static Point createRandomPoint(int min, int max) {
        Random r = new Random();
        double x = min + (max - min) * r.nextDouble();
        double y = min + (max - min) * r.nextDouble();
        return new Point(x,y);
    }

    protected static List createRandomPoints(int min, int max, int number) {
        List points = new ArrayList(number);
        for(int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            points.add(createRandomPoint(min,max));
        }
        return points;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "("+x+","+y+")";
    }
}
public class KMeans {

    //Number of Clusters. This metric should be related to the number of points
    private int NUM_CLUSTERS = 3;    
    //Number of Points
    private int NUM_POINTS = 15;
    //Min and Max X and Y
    private static final int MIN_COORDINATE = 0;
    private static final int MAX_COORDINATE = 10;

    private List points;
    private List clusters;

    public KMeans() {
        this.points = new ArrayList();
        this.clusters = new ArrayList();        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        KMeans kmeans = new KMeans();
        kmeans.init();
        kmeans.calculate();
    }

    //Initializes the process
    public void init() {
        //Create Points
        points = Point.createRandomPoints(MIN_COORDINATE,MAX_COORDINATE,NUM_POINTS);

        //Create Clusters
        //Set Random Centroids
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CLUSTERS; i++) {
            Cluster cluster = new Cluster(i);
            Point centroid = Point.createRandomPoint(MIN_COORDINATE,MAX_COORDINATE);
            cluster.setCentroid(centroid);
            clusters.add(cluster);
        }

        //Print Initial state
        plotClusters();
    }

    private void plotClusters() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CLUSTERS; i++) {
            Cluster c = clusters.get(i);
            c.plotCluster();
        }
    }

    //The process to calculate the K Means, with iterating method.
    public void calculate() {
        boolean finish = false;
        int iteration = 0;

        // Add in new data, one at a time, recalculating centroids with each new one. 
        while(!finish) {
            //Clear cluster state
            clearClusters();

            List lastCentroids = getCentroids();

            //Assign points to the closer cluster
            assignCluster();

            //Calculate new centroids.
            calculateCentroids();

            iteration++;

            List currentCentroids = getCentroids();

            //Calculates total distance between new and old Centroids
            double distance = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < lastCentroids.size(); i++) {
                distance += Point.distance(lastCentroids.get(i),currentCentroids.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println("#################");
            System.out.println("Iteration: " + iteration);
            System.out.println("Centroid distances: " + distance);
            plotClusters();

            if(distance == 0) {
                finish = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void clearClusters() {
        for(Cluster cluster : clusters) {
            cluster.clear();
        }
    }

    private List getCentroids() {
        List centroids = new ArrayList(NUM_CLUSTERS);
        for(Cluster cluster : clusters) {
            Point aux = cluster.getCentroid();
            Point point = new Point(aux.getX(),aux.getY());
            centroids.add(point);
        }
        return centroids;
    }

    private void assignCluster() {
        double max = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double min = max; 
        int cluster = 0;                 
        double distance = 0.0; 

        for(Point point : points) {
            min = max;
            for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CLUSTERS; i++) {
                Cluster c = clusters.get(i);
                distance = Point.distance(point, c.getCentroid());
                if(distance < min){
                    min = distance;
                    cluster = i;
                }
            }
            point.setCluster(cluster);
            clusters.get(cluster).addPoint(point);
        }
    }

    private void calculateCentroids() {
        for(Cluster cluster : clusters) {
            double sumX = 0;
            double sumY = 0;
            List list = cluster.getPoints();
            int n_points = list.size();

            for(Point point : list) {
                sumX += point.getX();
                sumY += point.getY();
            }

            Point centroid = cluster.getCentroid();
            if(n_points > 0) {
                double newX = sumX / n_points;
                double newY = sumY / n_points;
                centroid.setX(newX);
                centroid.setY(newY);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got the following erros. How to resolve them:

```
java:45: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type List
            clusters.add(cluster);
                        ^
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface List
/tmp/java_kmNqUn/KMeans.java:54: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Cluster
            Cluster c = clusters.get(i);
                                    ^
/tmp/java_kmNqUn/KMeans.java:84: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Point
                distance += Point.distance(lastCentroids.get(i),currentCentroids.get(i));
                                                            ^
/tmp/java_kmNqUn/KMeans.java:98: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Cluster
        for(Cluster cluster : clusters) {
                              ^
/tmp/java_kmNqUn/KMeans.java:105: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Cluster
        for(Cluster cluster : clusters) {
                              ^
/tmp/java_kmNqUn/KMeans.java:108: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type List
            centroids.add(point);
                         ^
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface List
/tmp/java_kmNqUn/KMeans.java:119: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Point
        for(Point point : points) {
                          ^
/tmp/java_kmNqUn/KMeans.java:122: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Cluster
                Cluster c = clusters.get(i);
                                        ^
/tmp/java_kmNqUn/KMeans.java:130: error: cannot find symbol
            clusters.get(cluster).addPoint(point);
                                 ^
  symbol:   method addPoint(Point)
  location: class Object
/tmp/java_kmNqUn/KMeans.java:135: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Cluster
        for(Cluster cluster : clusters) {
                              ^
/tmp/java_kmNqUn/KMeans.java:141: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Point
            for(Point point : list) {
                              ^
/tmp/java_kmNqUn/Point.java:61: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type List
            points.add(createRandomPoint(min,max));
                      ^
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface List
/tmp/java_kmNqUn/Cluster.java:27: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type List
        points.add(point);
                  ^
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface List
/tmp/java_kmNqUn/Cluster.java:54: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Point
        for(Point p : points) {
                      ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
10 errors
4 warnings*
```

please guide me...

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using a type `List` without any type parameters.  You should instead use a `List<SomeType>` (replacing `SomeType` with the relevant type).

Answer (score 0):

Using a strongly typed generic List with a type parameter is the best way of doing it.  If, however, you are forced to use an older version of Java that does not support generics, you could cast the cluster objects like this: `Cluster c = (Cluster)clusters.get(i);`